# Laravel testing fake event

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I am trying to fake event

```
public function should_assign_order()
{
    Event::fake([OrderWasAssigned::class]);
.
.
.
}
```

and I got this error

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Testing\Fakes\EventFake::getListeners()`
**Edit:**

I tried to disable telescope as [this issue](https://github.com/laravel/telescope/issues/573)
by `putenv('TELESCOPE_ENABLED=false');`
and same issue

I need fake only this event

I am on laravel 6

PHPUnit 9.5.4.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, then you are looking for scoped events as you want to test a specific event

```php
/**
* Test order process.
*/
    public function test_orders_can_be_processed()
    {
        $order = Event::fakeFor(function () {
            $order = Order::factory()->create();

            Event::assertDispatched(OrderCreated::class);

            return $order;
        });

        // Events are dispatched as normal and observers will run ...
        $order->update([...]);
    }
}
```

You can also read about it in the [laravels documentation about scoped events](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mocking#scoped-event-fakes)